# Get these edges whose degree is 2

Tags: graphs-and-networks, expression-construction

```
input = {13 -> 7, 7 -> 0, 0 -> 16, 16 -> 2, 2 -> 15, 10 -> 5, 5 -> 12,
    12 -> 18, 18 -> 15, 17 -> 18, 15 -> 6, 6 -> 8, 8 -> 4, 9 -> 8, 
   4 -> 19, 19 -> 11, 11 -> 1, 1 -> 20, 20 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 14 -> 19};
g = Graph[input, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image: img]

I can get it like

```
EdgeList[g, _?(ContainsOnly[
     Function[vertex, VertexDegree[g, vertex]] /@ List @@ #, {2}] &)]
```

[image]

But my confusion is why I cann't use this code to complete it??

```
EdgeList[g, 
 vertex_/;(ContainsOnly[VertexDegree[g, #] /@ List @@ vertex, {2}] &)]
```

What information I have missed?

Comment: @Kuba Just is a  common name of variable,I'm [this usage](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gbTr6.png)

Comment: It's undefinded symbol.The `vertex` like this code's `tem`.`Cases[Range@9, tem_ /; (tem > 5)]`.(And I have some confusion which symbol I should use,`/;` or `?`)

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, somehow I've missed you've named the pattern with it.

Answer (score 3):

```
input = {13 -> 7, 7 -> 0, 0 -> 16, 16 -> 2, 2 -> 15, 10 -> 5, 5 -> 12, 
   12 -> 18, 18 -> 15, 17 -> 18, 15 -> 6, 6 -> 8, 8 -> 4, 9 -> 8, 4 -> 19, 
   19 -> 11, 11 -> 1, 1 -> 20, 20 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 14 -> 19};
g = Graph[input, VertexLabels -> "Name"];

EdgeList[g, _?(ContainsOnly[
     Function[vertex, VertexDegree[g, vertex]] /@ List @@ #, {2}] &)]
```

[image]

The `&` must be at the end of the pure function being mapped , i.e.,

```
EdgeList[g, 
 vertex_ /; (ContainsOnly[VertexDegree[g, #] & /@ List @@ vertex, {2}])]
```

[image]

```
% === %%

True
```

Comment: Thanks for your direction,It seem I make a low-level mistake.:)